# TikZ back-compatibility broken from 3.0.1 to 3.1.9a when using "+(1,1)" style notation

Tags: tikz-pgf, backward-compatibility

This TikZ code is rendered differently by versions 3.0.1 and 3.1.9a:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
My TikZ version is \pgfversion.
\tikz{\draw (0,0) to [out=up, in=up] +(1,0) to +(0,1);}
\end{document}
```

Here are output examples:

[image][image]

This is a problem for me because I have an entire book written using TikZ code like this, and now in the modern version of TikZ it is not properly rendering. My book contains hundreds of figures. What can I do about this to make my pictures compile as originally intended?

I can guess why this is happening, but it's not really relevant, since the book has been written already.

Comment: well the old behaviour is clearly a bug, + shouldn't change the current point. You can probably get an older tikz version, e.g. from an historic texlive, but I would correct the code and replace the + by ++ where that was meant. Even with hundreds of figures it can't be so much work if only `to` pathes are affected.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I agree with you. Only for the fun try :  `\tikz{\draw (0,0) edge [out=up, in=up] +(-1,0) edge +(0,1);}`

Comment: Look at CHANGELOG.mg ## [3.1.8] - 2020-12-25 Henri Menke

### BREAKING CHANGES

Comment: Thanks all this is very interesting. I thought a golden rule of the latex ecosystem was never to make breaking changes!

Comment: It seems that in this case something was broken before and has been fixed in 3.1.8. In the change log, Henri writes *'Please open an issue if you rely on this'* (meaning the old behavior). File an issue on https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues;  maybe there is a patch to the current version than makes it behave like the old one. Or download an old version of tikz from there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can return to the old behavior (which in my opinion is broken) by simply disabling the internal macro `\tikz@updatenextfalse`, cf. https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/commit/8fb44f01cb320279a0e49dbd409a127c472f1903

Unless this is for backwards compatibility of an old document, I don't see why one would want to go back to the old behavior. Note that the LaTeX format itself also had a number of breaking changes over the last years. Don't conflate the stability guarantee of Knuth's original TeX engine with the rest of the ecosystem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\tikz@updatenexttrue % probably not necessary
\let\tikz@updatenextfalse\relax
\makeatother
\begin{document}
My TikZ version is \pgfversion.
\tikz{\draw (0,0) to [out=up, in=up] +(1,0) to +(0,1);}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this is great. Obviously I agree with everything you are saying, the old behaviour is broken, and I think my original post makes clear I want to do this for backwards compatibility purposes. Note that my logic was originally entirely sound when writing my book -- I used +(x,y) all the time, I never even knew ++ existed, and everything produced the output I wanted, because the specific features of my diagram meant I was always in this edge case that produced the unintended behaviour.